# Appindexing does not exist in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing an Android App using Android Studio and got error as

```
Error:(61, 127) error: package com.google.android.gms.appindexing does not exist
```

In the `build.gradle`, I have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
```

My Android Studio is version 1.5.1, just installed yesterday.

How can solve that problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

The latest version of Google Play Services App Indexing is:

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0`.

Make sure you update your Google Play Services dependencies in your Android SDK Manager first.

View versions: `ls ~/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/`

Comment: Yes I found in the folder ~/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/. Thanks

Comment: what about version 10 of play-services? I can't find app indexing on versions above 9.8

Comment: @JorgeArimany You are right, I do not see it there. Maybe it is a possible bug?